# How can you use a reference to the old array after calling ArrayPool.Resize?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

The Windows High Performance package includes Resize, an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.highperformance.extensions.arraypoolextensions.resize?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-6.1) that resizes arrays rented from System.Buffers.ArrayPool

At the end, they mention the following caveat:

> When this method returns, the caller must not use any references to
> the old array anymore.

I'm wondering if there's an example of code that would be using the previous reference, so that I can avoid such usage.
For instance, is this code using a reference to the old array?

```
T[] myPool;
public void Add(T item)
{
    if(Length >= myPool.Length)
        ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Resize(ref myPool, myPool.Length*2);
    myPool[Length++] = item;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not. That's because `ref myPool` is changing `myPool`. If you did `var oldArray = myPool`, then used `oldArray` afterwards, that would be an example of a disallowed pattern. More realistically `myPool` could have been passed to a method or stored somewhere before the call to `Resize`.

Comment: Note that this method is [nothing special](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance/Extensions/ArrayPoolExtensions.cs#L25), it essentially rents a new array, copies the existing data and returns the old one to the pool (no mystical in-place extension). This also explains why you can't use the original reference.